# Get null properties from an object

Tags: java

I have an object in that object am having nearly 30 properties i want to get all the null properties from the object.

Now am doing that by if condition for each and every property separately so my code is very big is there any way in java to get null properties from an object.

Please help to get this.

**EDIT** Am uploading my data i want to show the null fields to the user as an error message.

Comment: You could use reflection, but why would you want to do this?

Comment: You can use [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: Down voters please provide information for that so that i can learn

Comment: Can you put your *properties* into a collection of some sort?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis,Jereon can you please provide some code to do this am new to reflection

Comment: So you want to get every field of yours that is null?

Comment: @MonickaAkilan: I'd be glad to, if you try it first yourself. Here on SO we require a certain amount of effort from your side as well. If your question is still ongoing when I wake up and you have shown your attempt, I will provide a working solution tomorrow.

Comment: @Jereon Thank you for your comment. FUI i asked this que only before 5 min I will try and get back to you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you can get all the null fields using reflection:

```
    YourClassObject objectToIntrospect = new YourClassObject();
    for (Field field : objectToIntrospect.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true); // to allow the access of member attributes
        Object attribute = field.get(objectToIntrospect); 
        if (attribute == null) {
            System.out.println(field.getName() + "=" + attribute);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is hard to get new users to abide by the rules if they're not motivated to do so.. Just giving the code to these poor questions doesn't have a positive effect on the site in general (in my opinion).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I agree to your comment but partially. It depends on the kind of question. If something is too easy to explain in words then I will pick that path. But sometimes it is easier to describe things using code. The question sounds simple and answering that using reflection you can do this is also a fair statement. But as per my experience there are not many java coders who are well versed using reflection. At this instance considering the complexity of the concept itself, i thought of using the code instead text. I value your opinion and would consider it wherever possible.

Comment: Fair enough, you have a point. I would have preferred if an effort was shown by the asker, but your reasoning makes sense.

Comment: @JunedAhsan can you explain your code? To me it looks like you are casting the OPs object into an Object then you traverse the fields with a foreach. I don't understand what is the reflection aspect of this? Perhaps I just don't understand what reflection is: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: @MikeJohn That cast is not necessary, that was just for the sake of taking a user object. I have modified the first line to make it more comprehensible. Reflection allows the introspection of objects i.e. their fields and methods. It is hard to define reflection as part of a comment, but there are plenty of resources available online, just google.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need the [Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields%28%29). Then you [get the values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29), then add the [field name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getName%28%29) when the value is `null`. So, something like this -

```
public static String[] getNullFields(Object obj) {
  List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
  if (obj != null) {              // Check for null input.
    Class<?> cls = obj.getClass();
    Field[] fields = cls.getFields();
    for (Field f : fields) {
      try {
        if (f.get(obj) == null) { // Check for null value.
          al.add(f.getName());    // Add the field name.
        }
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
  String[] ret = new String[al.size()]; // Create a String[] to return.
  return al.toArray(ret);               // return as an Array.
}
```